# How do you install the copyright plug in in RubyMine?

Tags: plugins, rubymine

I searched for the plug in in the list that comes with RubyMine and it's not there, but it is present here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/88?pr=ruby

I just can't find the URL I need to add to my plug in repositories to have that plug in available.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to download the plugin from the [page you linked](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/88?pr=ruby) (there are links to download it) and **install the plugin from disk** in the Plugins settings in Rubymine.

However, this particular plugin seems to be *very* old and my quick attempt to install it was only partly successful. It appears as installed but I can't see it's configuration options available anywhere. I guess it's just way too old, unfortunately.